# How do I represent the graph of $\,\sin (x-2)\,$?

Tags: trigonometry

What does the graph of $\,\sin(x-2)\,$ look like? I have tried  putting values in $x$ but its getting complicated to represent it as a graph.

Comment: It is same as $\sin x$.

Comment: Is $x$ in degrees or radians? It's a horizontal shift (2 UNITS to the right)  nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

It looks just like the graph of $\sin (x)$ shifted to the right by $2$ units. If we define $x'=x-2$ you are graphing $\sin(x')$.  The origin of the $x'$ axis is at $x=2$

Comment: how can we find the values of y from this expression

Comment: You can just plug in values for $x$ and plot values of $y=\sin(x-2)=\sin(x')$  Or you can plug in values for $x'$, plot the $\sin(x')$ curve like you are used to, and show the $x$ axis offset by $2$ units from the $x'$ axis

Comment: ok..suppose  I put  x=7 then how do I plot sin 5 on the graph

Comment: My calculator shows $\sin 5 \approx 0.087$ so you would plot the point $(7,0.087)$  Isn't that what you would do to plot $\sin (x)?$